# Story about a library where every book possible is stored

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to work out the title and author of a story I remember reading. I think its a short story, about a library which housed only books of a certain length, but had every single combination of letters available meaning that every story possible was available, amongst all the junk and mess.

Within this library are different groups of people, for instance the fact that every combination of characters is available means that as well as history, the future is predicted so a group of fanatics hunt the library for the future.

Comment: Barely related, almost a curiosity: [libraryofbabel.info](https://libraryofbabel.info/)

Comment: [I had to..](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDrBIKOR01c)

Comment: Honorable mention for the Great Library in Jasper Fforde's *Thursday Next* metafiction novels which contains all books ever written or conceived.

Comment: I would also add Sandman by Nail Gaiman which contains a library with all the books, including the ones that were only dreamed.

Comment: Also L-Space from the Diskworld.

Comment: @alseether It's actually quite relevant, since the website is inspired by the story that's the answer to this question :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is very likely Jorge Luis Borges' short story ["The Library of Babel"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Library_of_Babel). In it, he describes a universe consisting of connected hexagonal rooms, each containing four walls with bookshelves.

While there's no definite proof, this vast library seems to contain all possible 410-page books possible with all combinations of 22 letters, a comma, a period, and a space.

The story was written in Spanish (as Borges was Argentinian) and was part of his 1941 collection *El Jardín de senderos que se bifurcan* (*The Garden of Forking Paths*), which was later expanded upon (the collection, not the story) and renamed *Ficciones* (*Fictions*).

The books are restricted to a certain format:

> There are five shelves for each of the hexagon's walls; each shelf contains 
>   thirty-five books of uniform format; each book is of four hundred and ten pages; 
>   each page, of forty lines, each line, of some eighty letters which are black in 
>   color. There are also letters on the spine of each book; these letters do not 
>   indicate or prefigure what the pages will say.

They had indeed had every single combination of letters available meaning that every story possible was available.

> This thinker observed that all the books, no matter how diverse they might be, are made up of the same elements: the space, the period, the comma, the twenty-two letters of the alphabet.  He also alleged a fact which travelers have confirmed: In the vast Library there are no two identical books. From these two incontrovertible premises he deduced that the Library is total and that its shelves register all the possible combinations of the twenty-odd orthographical symbols [...]

There *is* a group of fanatics that hunt the library for the future.

> There are official searchers, inquisitors. I have seen them in the performance of their function: they always arrive extremely tired from their journeys; [...]

Others destroy books they deem nonsense.

> Others, inversely, believed that it was fundamental to eliminate useless works. They invaded the hexagons, showed credentials which were not always false, leafed through a volume with displeasure and condemned whole shelves: their hygienic, ascetic furor caused the senseless perdition of millions of books.

You can [read it on the *Internet Archive*](https://archive.org/details/TheLibraryOfBabel).

Comment: For additional reference for anyone interested, a copy of this question and answer with extensive commentary can also be found in the Library of Babel.

Comment: [The Net of Babel](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47000) by David Langford further expands on the subject, imagining that the Library has been digitalized. It removes the illusion that the problem is in the size of the Library (a typical Borges red herring).

Comment: While Borges may well have been the first, a lot of authors have since explored variations of this idea. For a recent example, see [this SMBC comic](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/the-library-of-heaven).

Comment: [It was the best of times, it was the *blurst" of times?!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=no_elVGGgW8)

Comment: I have digitized this library. I store it at `/dev/random`.

Comment: Willy Ley discussed this idea in [_Postscript to "The Universal Library"_](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?97311), following Kurd Lasswitz' [_The Universal Library_](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?97312) which was originally published in 1904 and translated into English in 1958 for the anthology _Fantasia Mathematica_.

Comment: This answer can be found here https://libraryofbabel.info/bookmark.cgi?i_qoff.wypm.bvlopgvm.qk_f191

Comment: @Tim [as can your comment](https://libraryofbabel.info/bookmark.cgi?vnhzrjn_ick,tvi_t345) :D

Comment: @mattdm Can you `rsync` that to me? Please use `-z` or it'll take _forever._

Comment: @mattdm It seems to have been compressed somehow. I'm sad!

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: I'm not! It is fundamental to cut down useless works.

Comment: *Four* walls with books, not five. Otherwise there'd only be two rooms.

Comment: @jcm you're right, I interpreted that quote wrong and overlooked another line. It's indeed four walls per hexagon, not five.

Comment: That is exactly the story I was thinking of, thanks to all for the other suggestions

Comment: See [Borges' Number](https://people.smp.uq.edu.au/MichaelBulmer/stuff/borges.php)... the number of books is 25 (22 letters + space, period, comma) to the power 1,321,000 (=410 x 40 x 80) which is 1834098 digits long. That would need an _awful_ lot of rooms!

Answer (score 1):

In one of the Discworld books by Terry Pratchett, the Librarian has access to all libraries and all books. It is a secret. I've seen that section excerpt from books before, but it doesn't sound like an exact match to your description.
https://discworld.fandom.com/wiki/The_Librarian

Comment: It's a regular theme that the Librarian uses L-space to get to all sorts of times and places. The HEM department also look into future unprinted works, but this wouldn't match for the question.

Comment: He uses L-space regularly? Hrmmm. I must've missed that theme. Thank you. I was more wondering if the theme/short got excerpted but, as you said, it doesn't match the description very well.

Comment: I think "occasionally" would be a better term. Its dangerous and something he only does when necessary, but of course we tend to focus on those occasions. Narativium and all that.